# What are the different effects that we can use for hide/show in jquery ui tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I was trying to implement jQuery UI tabs and know about effects such as `slideUp`, `fadeIn`, `hide`, and `show`. What other effects can be used? For example, explode was not working. Is there any place where I can get a list of all the effects that can be used with jQuery UI tabs?

Also is there any way to implement custom animation; can you tell me how I can use explode for hide?

Answer (score 2):

> **"can you tell me how I can use explode for hide."**

Did you even consider reading the [jQuery UI tabs documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/), which actually includes an example of [hiding with "explode"](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-hide):

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 } });
```

You can easily combine this with the same or a different effect to `show`, as well:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 },
    show: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T4rst/

> **"Is there any place where I can get a list of all the effects that can be used with jquery-ui tabs."**

Well as that same documentation page says:

> *"The value can either be the name of a built-in jQuery animation method, such as "slideUp", or the name of a jQuery UI effect, such as "fold".*

So there is a list of jQuery UI effects [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/), plus the standard jQuery ones apply.

Answer (score 0):

Check it for details. It may helps for your issues :http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/